# The find command: the options '-mindepth' conflicts with the action '-prune'

Tags: find

If the file structure is like this:

```
/a/p/c/d...
/c/a/c/g/f/...
/a/c/d/e/...
...
```

And I want to do this:

`find -mindepth 3 -type d -name p -prune -or -name c -print`

However, this command will not prune the 'p' directory and the first line will included. I know it's actually not a conflict. But how to prune 'p' with the mindepth applied?

Comment: I take it that `d` and `e` are files, not directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would do it this way:

```
find -mindepth 3 -type d ! -path '*/p/*' -name c -print
```

Based on @StephaneChazelas' feedback I believe this method would eliminate the extraneous searching into any `/p/` directories:

```
find -mindepth 3 -type d -path '*/p/*' -prune -o -name c -print
```

#### Analyzing a find

To compare find commands you can add the debug switch `-D search` so that you can see how a particular find would perform vs. another.

I ran @StephaneChazelas' command vs. mine to see where the differences were. The 2 commands are run and their output is run into an `sdiff` below:

```
$ sdiff \
<(find -D search -mindepth 3 -type d -path '*/p/*' -prune -o -name c -print 2>&1) \
<(find -D search -type d -name p -prune -o -path './*/*/*' -name c -print 2>&1)
consider_visiting (early): `.': fts_info=FTS_D , fts_level= 0   consider_visiting (early): `.': fts_info=FTS_D , fts_level= 0
consider_visiting (late): `.': fts_info=FTS_D , isdir=1 ignor | consider_visiting (late): `.': fts_info=FTS_D , isdir=1 ignor
consider_visiting (early): `./a': fts_info=FTS_D , fts_level=   consider_visiting (early): `./a': fts_info=FTS_D , fts_level=
consider_visiting (late): `./a': fts_info=FTS_D , isdir=1 ign | consider_visiting (late): `./a': fts_info=FTS_D , isdir=1 ign
consider_visiting (early): `./a/c': fts_info=FTS_D , fts_leve   consider_visiting (early): `./a/c': fts_info=FTS_D , fts_leve
consider_visiting (late): `./a/c': fts_info=FTS_D , isdir=1 i | consider_visiting (late): `./a/c': fts_info=FTS_D , isdir=1 i
consider_visiting (early): `./a/c/d': fts_info=FTS_D , fts_le   consider_visiting (early): `./a/c/d': fts_info=FTS_D , fts_le
consider_visiting (late): `./a/c/d': fts_info=FTS_D , isdir=1   consider_visiting (late): `./a/c/d': fts_info=FTS_D , isdir=1
consider_visiting (early): `./a/c/d/e': fts_info=FTS_D , fts_   consider_visiting (early): `./a/c/d/e': fts_info=FTS_D , fts_
consider_visiting (late): `./a/c/d/e': fts_info=FTS_D , isdir   consider_visiting (late): `./a/c/d/e': fts_info=FTS_D , isdir
consider_visiting (early): `./a/c/d/e': fts_info=FTS_DP, fts_   consider_visiting (early): `./a/c/d/e': fts_info=FTS_DP, fts_
consider_visiting (late): `./a/c/d/e': fts_info=FTS_DP, isdir   consider_visiting (late): `./a/c/d/e': fts_info=FTS_DP, isdir
consider_visiting (early): `./a/c/d': fts_info=FTS_DP, fts_le   consider_visiting (early): `./a/c/d': fts_info=FTS_DP, fts_le
consider_visiting (late): `./a/c/d': fts_info=FTS_DP, isdir=1   consider_visiting (late): `./a/c/d': fts_info=FTS_DP, isdir=1
consider_visiting (early): `./a/c': fts_info=FTS_DP, fts_leve   consider_visiting (early): `./a/c': fts_info=FTS_DP, fts_leve
consider_visiting (late): `./a/c': fts_info=FTS_DP, isdir=1 i   consider_visiting (late): `./a/c': fts_info=FTS_DP, isdir=1 i
consider_visiting (early): `./a/p': fts_info=FTS_D , fts_leve   consider_visiting (early): `./a/p': fts_info=FTS_D , fts_leve
consider_visiting (late): `./a/p': fts_info=FTS_D , isdir=1 i | consider_visiting (late): `./a/p': fts_info=FTS_D , isdir=1 i
consider_visiting (early): `./a/p/c': fts_info=FTS_D , fts_le | consider_visiting (early): `./a/p': fts_info=FTS_DP, fts_leve
consider_visiting (late): `./a/p/c': fts_info=FTS_D , isdir=1 <
consider_visiting (early): `./a/p/c': fts_info=FTS_DP, fts_le <
consider_visiting (late): `./a/p/c': fts_info=FTS_DP, isdir=1 <
consider_visiting (early): `./a/p': fts_info=FTS_DP, fts_leve <
consider_visiting (late): `./a/p': fts_info=FTS_DP, isdir=1 i   consider_visiting (late): `./a/p': fts_info=FTS_DP, isdir=1 i
consider_visiting (early): `./a': fts_info=FTS_DP, fts_level=   consider_visiting (early): `./a': fts_info=FTS_DP, fts_level=
consider_visiting (late): `./a': fts_info=FTS_DP, isdir=1 ign   consider_visiting (late): `./a': fts_info=FTS_DP, isdir=1 ign
consider_visiting (early): `./c': fts_info=FTS_D , fts_level=   consider_visiting (early): `./c': fts_info=FTS_D , fts_level=
consider_visiting (late): `./c': fts_info=FTS_D , isdir=1 ign | consider_visiting (late): `./c': fts_info=FTS_D , isdir=1 ign
consider_visiting (early): `./c/a': fts_info=FTS_D , fts_leve   consider_visiting (early): `./c/a': fts_info=FTS_D , fts_leve
consider_visiting (late): `./c/a': fts_info=FTS_D , isdir=1 i | consider_visiting (late): `./c/a': fts_info=FTS_D , isdir=1 i
consider_visiting (early): `./c/a/c': fts_info=FTS_D , fts_le   consider_visiting (early): `./c/a/c': fts_info=FTS_D , fts_le
consider_visiting (late): `./c/a/c': fts_info=FTS_D , isdir=1   consider_visiting (late): `./c/a/c': fts_info=FTS_D , isdir=1
consider_visiting (early): `./c/a/c/g': fts_info=FTS_D , fts_   consider_visiting (early): `./c/a/c/g': fts_info=FTS_D , fts_
consider_visiting (late): `./c/a/c/g': fts_info=FTS_D , isdir   consider_visiting (late): `./c/a/c/g': fts_info=FTS_D , isdir
consider_visiting (early): `./c/a/c/g/f': fts_info=FTS_D , ft   consider_visiting (early): `./c/a/c/g/f': fts_info=FTS_D , ft
consider_visiting (late): `./c/a/c/g/f': fts_info=FTS_D , isd   consider_visiting (late): `./c/a/c/g/f': fts_info=FTS_D , isd
consider_visiting (early): `./c/a/c/g/f': fts_info=FTS_DP, ft   consider_visiting (early): `./c/a/c/g/f': fts_info=FTS_DP, ft
consider_visiting (late): `./c/a/c/g/f': fts_info=FTS_DP, isd   consider_visiting (late): `./c/a/c/g/f': fts_info=FTS_DP, isd
consider_visiting (early): `./c/a/c/g': fts_info=FTS_DP, fts_   consider_visiting (early): `./c/a/c/g': fts_info=FTS_DP, fts_
consider_visiting (late): `./c/a/c/g': fts_info=FTS_DP, isdir   consider_visiting (late): `./c/a/c/g': fts_info=FTS_DP, isdir
consider_visiting (early): `./c/a/c': fts_info=FTS_DP, fts_le   consider_visiting (early): `./c/a/c': fts_info=FTS_DP, fts_le
consider_visiting (late): `./c/a/c': fts_info=FTS_DP, isdir=1   consider_visiting (late): `./c/a/c': fts_info=FTS_DP, isdir=1
consider_visiting (early): `./c/a': fts_info=FTS_DP, fts_leve   consider_visiting (early): `./c/a': fts_info=FTS_DP, fts_leve
consider_visiting (late): `./c/a': fts_info=FTS_DP, isdir=1 i   consider_visiting (late): `./c/a': fts_info=FTS_DP, isdir=1 i
consider_visiting (early): `./c': fts_info=FTS_DP, fts_level=   consider_visiting (early): `./c': fts_info=FTS_DP, fts_level=
consider_visiting (late): `./c': fts_info=FTS_DP, isdir=1 ign   consider_visiting (late): `./c': fts_info=FTS_DP, isdir=1 ign
consider_visiting (early): `.': fts_info=FTS_DP, fts_level= 0   consider_visiting (early): `.': fts_info=FTS_DP, fts_level= 0
consider_visiting (late): `.': fts_info=FTS_DP, isdir=1 ignor   consider_visiting (late): `.': fts_info=FTS_DP, isdir=1 ignor
./c/a/c                             ./c/a/c
```

If you notice, there's a gap in Stephane's approach that mine doesn't have. Even with the prune. I think this shows that his method is avoiding extra work in walking into directories that it should otherwise be ignoring.

Comment: That still causes `find` to descend into the `p` directories though.

Comment: Yes, as `-prune` can't prune in this situation, filtering maybe the only option left.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas, would something like this address your point? `find -mindepth 3 -type d -path '*/p/*' -prune -o -name c -print`.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. I forgot I can prune the path! Thank you! (This should be added to your answer.)

Comment: @Bohr, just updated it.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas, could you please review what I wrote in the answer. Are my assumptions and intepretations correct?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something your `sdiff` output shows that mine requires less effort (the gap). If `-name p -prune` doesn't work `-path '*/p/*' -prune` doesn't work either (`-prune` is like `-true`).

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - Thanks for taking a look, that was my understanding as well, your method is better b/c the `-name p -prune` appears to stop recursing into any `p` directories while the `-path '*/p/*'` does not. I don't quite understand why the `-path` is getting into the `p` directories though. Any ideas?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - I think I know the issue, it's the trialing `*`. It matches the content inside the directory but doesn't recurse beyond that. My sample data didn't go beyond that, i belive if I remove the `*` then we should be seeing similar results.

Comment: Well, no. At least with `-path '*/p/*'` it would prune the subdirs of `p` that are at depth 3 and above, while with `-path '*/p'`, it prunes only the `p`s that are 3 level deep (so doesn't answer the question). `-path '*/p'` is the same as `-name p`.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - doesn't look like that trailing `*` can be removed, so the best my approach can do is as it is. Worst case scenario is that it "leaks" by doing one additional directories worth of files, ie. everything just under the directory `/p/`, but it doesn't recurse beyond that. Good to chat with you, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

With both FreeBSD and GNU `find` (which are some of the few implementations that support `-mindepth`), your `-prune` would only prune the `p` directories that are at depth 3 or deeper. Both the FreeBSD and GNU `find` documentation make it quite clear (here GNU documentation):

> ```
> -- Option: -mindepth levels
>     Do not apply any tests or actions at levels less than LEVELS (a
>     non-negative integer).  `-mindepth 1' means process all files
>     except the command line arguments.
> ```

You could always do it the standard way instead:

```
find . -type d -name p -prune -o -path './*/*/*' -name c -print
```

(`-mindepth` and `-or` are not standard `find` predicates, omitting the directory(s) is not standard either).

Or with `zsh`:

```
setopt extendedglob
printf '%s\n' ^p/^p/(^p/)#c
```

Comment: Just curious, why do you say this way is the "standard" way? Because you used `-o` instead of `-or`?

Comment: @slm, the last sentence should make it clear.

Comment: I see the note in the man page now, it says `-or` is the same as `-o` but not POSIX compliance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the man page of find:

```
 -prune True;  if  the  file is a directory, do not descend into it. If
        -depth is given, false; no  effect.
```

So in your particular case I would do something like:

```
 find a/* -mindepth 2  -type f -print
```

But of course there is not always such an easy solution.

Comment: Sorry I should make it more clear!